# What will the assign statements get synthesized as?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I am interested to know what will these lines synthesize to? I am designing a direct mapped cache and using assign to separate my index, offset and tag bits. Will it synthesize to a demultiplexer? I did not mention the whole code since I just want to know how the assign statements will look after synthesis. In 8085 programming, I had read the term as 'address demultiplexing" so it was confusing.

```
module cache 
        (   input bit clk,
            input bit rst,
            input logic [15:0] address,
            input logic valid_in,
            input logic compare,
            input logic wr,
            input logic enable,
            input logic write_through,
            output logic dirty,
            output logic [4:0] tag_out,
            output logic [15:0] data_out,
            output logic valid_out,
            output hit
        );

            logic [7:0] index;
            logic [1:0] offset;
            logic [4:0] tag_in;

            assign offset = address[1:0];
            assign index  = address[9:2];
            assign tag_in = address[15:10];

    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no Boolean or arithmetic operators on the RHS of the `assign`, these statements just become conveniently named references for part selects of the `address` input. This is the same thing that happens when you instantiate a module and connect to its ports - signals can go through a name change. In fact, you could have you could have written your `address` input port declaration as

```
input .address({tag_in,index,offset}),
```

You still connect the `address` port when instantiating this module, but inside the module, it only has tag_in, index, and offset available to reference, not address.

SystemVerilog has the `alias` construct to make it more obvious that you are just creating a convenient names for a signal, instead of declaring another set of signals and using the `assign` statement.

```
 alias offset = address[1:0];
 alias index  = address[9:2];
 alias tag_in = address[15:10];
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code will just simply get synthesized as wire's, since there are only assignments. 
I am not sure what de-multiplexing logic you are trying to create, but generally for a de-multiplexer you need to have a select signal based on which you decode which output should be enabled.

An example for a 1:2 de-multiplexer logic is given below

```
module demux_1_2(
   input [3:0] Q, 
   input Sel,
   output reg [3:0] D1, 
   output reg [3:0] D2
   );

always@(*) 
begin
   if(~Sel) begin 
      D1 = Q;
      D2 = 0; 
   end else begin 
      D1 = 0; 
      D2 = Q; 
   end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: So my question here is what logic will the hardware use to separate the different bits of the address signal?

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji Harware needn't use any logic since there is no logic in your code. It is just like interconnecting two wires.

Comment: would using always_comb had also inferred the same as assign?

Comment: yes. 
`always_comb begin 
  D1 = ~sel ? Q : 0;
  D2 =   sel ? Q : 0;
end`